# VBA question how to correctly use Loop function

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a simple loop in VBA.

The idea is that it checks 2 times. If Time1 < Time 2 it should return the amount of loops done.

If not we add a loop

This kicks a error as a IN statement is acpected but not sure how to write that in here.

Sorry for my ignorance

```
Function Test()
AmountofLoops = 1
Time1 = 0.5
Time2 = 0.1

For Each Time2 < Time1
If (Time2 < Time1) then
Time1 = Time1 - 0.1
AmountofLoops = AmountofLoops + 1
End If
Next
Test = AmountofLoops
End Function
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-for-eachnext-statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Do While`-Loop for that. It will loop while a condition is `True` - therefore you don't need an extra `If`-statement:

```
Do While Time2 < Time1
    Time1 = Time1 - 0.1
    AmountofLoops = AmountofLoops + 1
Loop
```

You use a `For`-Loop when you know already the number of times you want to execute the loop, for example `For i=1 To 10`, or to loop over an Array: `For i = LBound(myArr) to UBound(myArr)`. You always need a counter variable using a `For`-Loop.

You use a `For Each`-Loop when you want to loop over a collection or something the like: `For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets`. You need a counter variable of the according type (in this case of type `Worksheet`).

If `Time1` and `Time2` are fixed values (that doesn't change within the loop), you could maybe use a `For`-Loop in the following way:

```
For timeVar from Time2 to Time1 Step 0.1
    AmountofLoops = AmountofLoops + 1
Next
```

or

```
For timeVar from Time1 to Time2 Step -0.1
    AmountofLoops = AmountofLoops + 1
Next
```